# Laravel 4 (4.2.8) Generate model in app folder and not model

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

When I run this command

```
php artisan generate:model Post
```

it generates the Post.php at app/Post.php and not in model. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: `generate:model` is not available in Laravel 3. Did you mean Laravel 4.2 or 4.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force the path by adding path option

Try this

```
php artisan generate:model Post --path=app/models
```

The reason it is placing new file in app directory is because you must have edited the path in your config file.

See more about [configurations](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators#configuration)